# How install custom pepper plugin in Chromium browser source code?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, google-nativeclient

I need to build in my pepper plugin in chromium source code for building browser with already installed plugin. Is there possibility to do that?

Answer (score 0):

A handful of plugins are built in. Since these are plugins, they are built independently from Chrome and loaded dynamically rather than directly linked to the Chromium executable. This is the function that causes them to be loaded into Chromium:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/common/chrome_content_client.cc&rcl=1436599777&l=118

The NaCl plugin is special, since it runs "in process", which means it is loaded into the renderer process. Eventually, support for this kind of plugin will be eliminated, so it is best to follow the pattern of the "out of process" plugins, which run in their own process, such as PDF.